# Parameter can't be used in the select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, error-handling, plsqldeveloper

I have one task to solve.

Create a function that returns the name of the department (department_name) in which employee works based on the employee_id.

Treat the case if employee is not assigned to  department.

Use the function created in the SQL statement. List the first and last name, start date, and department name for employee_id 160.

I have this, but there is an error: the expression 'EMP_ID' cannot be used as the INTO target of a SELECT / FETCH statement.

What am I doing wrong?

```
create or replace function oddelenie(emp_id in employees.employee_id%type)
return varchar is dept_name departments.department_name%type;
begin
select employee_id, department_name into emp_id, dept_name
from employees join departments using (department_id);
return dept_name;
        exception when no_data_found then
            dbms_output.put_line('error');
end oddelenie;
```

Thank you.

Comment: I would seriously reconsider `exception when no_data_found then dbms_output.put_line('error');` Also it's **varchar2**, not [varchar](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#SQLRF-GUID-DF7E10FC-A461-4325-A295-3FD4D150809E).

Answer (score 2):

Select only what you need - department name. What would you do with employee's ID; you already know it, you passed it as a parameter.

```
create or replace function oddelenie
  (par_emp_id in employees.employee_id%type)
  return varchar2
is 
  l_dept_name departments.department_name%type;
begin
  select department_name 
    into l_dept_name
  from employees join departments using (department_id)
  where employee_id = par_emp_id;

  return dept_name;

exception when no_data_found then
  return 'error';
end oddelenie;
```

Comment: Thank you :) @Littlefoot

Answer (score 1):

`emp_id` is an input parameter so it doesn't make sense for your `select` statement to try to overwrite its value.  Presumably you want to use the `emp_id` to filter down your results to a single row.  Something like

```
create or replace function oddelenie(emp_id in employees.employee_id%type)
  return varchar 
is 
  dept_name departments.department_name%type;
begin
  select d.department_name 
    into dept_name
    from employees e
         join departments d using (department_id)
   where e.employee_id = emp_id;
  return dept_name;
exception when no_data_found then
  dbms_output.put_line('error');
end oddelenie;
```

Note that your exception handler is worse than useless.  An exception handler that merely writes something to `dbms_output` only serves to swallow exceptions.  You have no idea whether the caller will ever actually even see something written to `dbms_output` or whether the caller will proceed blissfully along unaware that the process failed.  It would be vastly better to remove the exception handler entirely.  If you want to keep it, return some placeholder string, i.e.

```
exception
  when no_data_found
  then
    return 'No department';
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, it was very helpful :)

Comment: I would also like to ask you how can I call this function to print the name, surname and name of the department? @JustinCave

Comment: @Kristina - Probably something like `select name, surname, oddelenie(employee_id) department_name from employees`.  It would generally make sense to pick a more descriptive name for the function (i.e. `get_department_name` )

Comment: I tried this :```select first_name, last_name, oddelenie(107), hire_date from employees;``` but it returns all employees and I only need information about employee_id 107. Thank you :)

Comment: @Kristina - Then add a `where` clause on the `employee_id`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now! :) @Justin

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared `emp_id`:

```
create or replace function oddelenie(emp_id in employees.employee_id%type)
return varchar 
is 
   dept_name departments.department_name%type;
   employee_id employees.employee_id%type;
begin
select employee_id, department_name into employee_id, dept_name
from employees join departments using (department_id);
return dept_name;
        exception when no_data_found then
            dbms_output.put_line('error');
end oddelenie;
```

Your parameter `emp_id` is an IN parameter. Declare it as an `IN OUT` or declare another variable to hold the value.

Comment: Thank you :) @gmiley